How to write an expression as a ratio of polynomials
I have the following Mathematica expression as a result of some calculations:
4 ρ ω x_j + 2 s_i α_i - 2 x_i (2 ρ ω + α_i)
   + α_j (-2 ρ - 2 s_i + 2 x_j + (2 (s_i - x_i) α_i)/(ω (x_i - x_j))
   + ((-rd_i + rs_i) γ_i)/(ω (d_i - s_i) (x_i - x_j) ζ_i))
   + ((-rd_i + rs_i) γ_i)/((d_i - s_i) ζ_i) - (2 ω (rd_i - rs_i) (d_i - s_i) (x_i - x_j) γ_j)/((rd_i - rs_i) γ_i
   + 2 (d_i - s_i) (ω (ρ - d_j + s_i) (x_i - x_j) + (-s_i + x_i) α_i) ζ_i)

I would like to express this result as a ratio of polynomials in s_i, but I am not aware of any Mathematica instruction that can do that. Can anyone help me, please?

Naming variables like s_i is not a proper way to do it in Mathemaitca. _ is reserved for other purposes. You can name it like si or s[i] instead.

First fix your code, as explained by azerbajdzan. Then, do you mean as an approximation or exact? Look into PadeApproximant.

Do you mean like Together? or Simplify? or FullSimplify? or Factor? I feel like each one of these might end up doing what you want. And by, for instance, rs_i do you mean r*s_i or (rs)_i (i.e., rs is a single variable name)?

In Mathematic "a_b" has the special meaning as input notation yielding Pattern[a,Blank[b]]. Test it by FullForm[a_b],
If your $a\_b$ notation is TeX subscript convert your expression to Normal by Replacing the function Pattern by Subscript and the Blank pattern function by the Identity function in order to replace it by its name. Finally combine sums of fraction over a common denominator and try to Simplify
(4 \[Rho] \[Omega] x_j + 2 s_i \[Alpha]_i - 
 2 x_i (2 \[Rho] \[Omega] + \[Alpha]_i)
 + \[Alpha]_j (-2 \[Rho] - 2 s_i + 
    2 x_j + (2 (s_i - x_i) \[Alpha]_i)/(\[Omega] (x_i - 
         x_j)) + ((-rd_i + rs_i) \[Gamma]_i)/(\[Omega] (d_i - 
         s_i) (x_i - x_j) \[Zeta]_i))
  +((-rd_i + rs_i) \[Gamma]_i)/((d_i - 
       s_i) \[Zeta]_i) - (2 \[Omega] (rd_i - rs_i) (d_i - 
      s_i) (x_i - x_j) \[Gamma]_j)/((rd_i - rs_i) \[Gamma]_i + 
    2 (d_i - 
       s_i) (\[Omega] (\[Rho] - d_j + s_i) (x_i - x_j) + (-s_i + 
          x_i) \[Alpha]_i) \[Zeta]_i)) //. 
      { Pattern :> Subscript, Blank -> Identity} // 
Together // FullSimplify

